# Jquery Conflict which gives error

Tags: javascript, jquery-ui, jquery, jquery-plugins

Working on an project which has variety of functionality in it such as,

- Google translator
- Image Slider [galleriffic used]
- Popup window [Shadow box used]
- JavaScript horizontal menu bar*

**Now we are getting jquery conflict in it and error message such as** 
[image: Error Message]

**I know such message are occurred when the code doesn't find the jquery file but the files is present .**

Here are the list of files used in the project
This is needed by the google translator

```
    1.<script type="text/javascript" src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7/jquery.min.js"></script>
    2. <script type="text/javascript" src="//jquery-translate.googlecode.com/files/jquery.translate-1.3.7.min.js"></script>
    3. <script type="text/javascript" src="/scripts/jQuery/jquery.cookie.js"></script>
    4.  <script type="text/javascript" src="/scripts/jquery.bt.js"></script>
    5. <script type="text/javascript" src="/scripts/jquery-ui-1.8.21.custom.min.js"></script>
    6. <script type="text/javascript" src="/fancybox/jquery.fancybox.pack.js"></script>
    7. <script type="text/javascript" src="/scripts/common.js"></script>
```

This one is for the slider

```
    1.  <script type="text/javascript" src="/SliderBox/js/jquery-1.3.2.js"></script>
    2.  <script type="text/javascript" src="/SliderBox/js/jquery.galleriffic.js"></script>
    3.  <script type="text/javascript" src="/SliderBox/js/jquery.opacityrollover.js"></script>
```

This is for the popup window

```
    1. <script type="text/javascript" src="/SliderBox/js/prototype.js"></script>
    2. <script type="text/javascript" src="/SliderBox/js/effects.js"></script>
    3. <script type="text/javascript" src="/SliderBox/js/lightwindow.js"></script>
    4. <script type="text/javascript" src="/SliderBox/shadowbox/shadowbox.js"></script>
```

This is needed by the horizontal menu

```
    1. <script type="text/javascript" src="./jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
    2. <script src="../scripts/jquery.als-1.1.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    3. <script src="../scripts/settingsEN.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

**I have optimized all these and have included only one jquery file of jquery-1.9.1.min.js
but still not able to clear the conflict
Here is the sequence used by me**

```
    1. <script type="text/javascript" src="./jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
    2.<script type="text/javascript" src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7/jquery.min.js"></script>
    3. <script type="text/javascript" src="//jquery-translate.googlecode.com/files/jquery.translate-1.3.7.min.js"></script>
    4. <script type="text/javascript" src="/scripts/jQuery/jquery.cookie.js"></script>
    5.  <script type="text/javascript" src="/scripts/jquery.bt.js"></script>
    6. <script type="text/javascript" src="/scripts/jquery-ui-1.8.21.custom.min.js"></script>
    7. <script type="text/javascript" src="/fancybox/jquery.fancybox.pack.js"></script>
    8. <script type="text/javascript" src="/scripts/common.js"></script>
    9. <script type="text/javascript" src="/SliderBox/js/jquery.galleriffic.js"></script>
    10.  <script type="text/javascript" src="/SliderBox/js/jquery.opacityrollover.js"></script>
    11.<script type="text/javascript" src="/SliderBox/js/prototype.js"></script>
    12. <script type="text/javascript" src="/SliderBox/js/effects.js"></script>
    13. <script type="text/javascript" src="/SliderBox/js/lightwindow.js"></script>
    14. <script type="text/javascript" src="/SliderBox/shadowbox/shadowbox.js"></script>
    15.<script src="../scripts/jquery.als-1.1.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    16. <script src="../scripts/settingsEN.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

I have tried all these

http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.noConflict/

http://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/avoid-conflicts-other-libraries/?rdfrom=http%3A%2F%2Fdocs.jquery.com%2Fmw%2Findex.php%3Ftitle%3DUsing_jQuery_with_Other_Libraries%26redirect%3Dno

http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/jquery_noconflict.asp

I have tried all these

```
 <script type="text/javascript" src="other_lib.js"></script>
 <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.js"></script>
 <script type="text/javascript">
 $.noConflict();
 // Code that uses other library's $ can follow here.
 </script>
```

or

```
 <script type="text/javascript" src="other_lib.js"></script>
 <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.js"></script>
 <script type="text/javascript">
 $.noConflict();
 jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
 // Code that uses jQuery's $ can follow here.
  });
 // Code that uses other library's $ can follow here.
 </script>
```

or

```
jQuery.noConflict();
(function($) {
 $(function() {
  // more code using $ as alias to jQuery
 });
})(jQuery);
// other code using $ as an alias to the other library
```

but still not able to get the Solution

When I remove this code of slider, every thing works fine , no errors but the slider will not work

```
 <!--script for slider--->

      <script type="text/javascript">

  jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    // We only want these styles applied when javascript is enabled
    $('div.navigation').css({'width' : '', 'float' : 'right'});
    $('div.content').css('display', 'block');

    // Initially set opacity on thumbs and add
    // additional styling for hover effect on thumbs
    var onMouseOutOpacity = 0.67;
    $('#thumbs ul.thumbs li').opacityrollover({
      mouseOutOpacity:   onMouseOutOpacity,
      mouseOverOpacity:  1.0,
      fadeSpeed:         'fast',
      exemptionSelector: '.selected'
    });

    // Initialize Advanced Galleriffic Gallery
    var gallery = $('#thumbs').galleriffic({
      delay:                     2500,
      numThumbs:                 15,
      preloadAhead:              10,
      enableTopPager:            true,
      enableBottomPager:         true,
      maxPagesToShow:            7,
      imageContainerSel:         '#slideshow',
      controlsContainerSel:      '#controls',
      captionContainerSel:       '#caption',
      loadingContainerSel:       '#loading',
      renderSSControls:          true,
      renderNavControls:         true,
      random:                    true,
      prevLinkText:              '',
      nextLinkText:              '',
      nextPageLinkText:          '',
      playLinkText:              '',
      pauseLinkText:             '',
      prevPageLinkText:          '',
      enableHistory:             false,
      autoStart:                 false,
      syncTransitions:           true,
      defaultTransitionDuration: 900,
      onSlideChange:             function(prevIndex, nextIndex) {
        // 'this' refers to the gallery, which is an extension of $('#thumbs')
        this.find('ul.thumbs').children()
          .eq(prevIndex).fadeTo('fast', onMouseOutOpacity).end()
          .eq(nextIndex).fadeTo('fast', 1.0);
      },
      onPageTransitionOut:       function(callback) {
        this.fadeTo('fast', 0.0, callback);
      },
      onPageTransitionIn:        function() {
        this.fadeTo('fast', 1.0);
      }
    });
  });
</script>



  <!--script end--->
```

**Can anyone help?**

Comment: useful tip: don't ever look at w3schools! Also try to move jquery-ui-1.8.21.custom.min.js just after jquery-1.9.1.min.js

Comment: I think that this line `<script type="text/javascript" src="/SliderBox/js/prototype.js"></script>` is overwriting the jQuery function (because [prototype.js](http://prototypejs.org/) has `$` function for itself).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*I went with this flow and the error was solved.* **Didn't need any .noConflict() and on!!!**

```
1)<script type="text/javascript" src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7/jquery.min.js"></script>
2)<script type="text/javascript" src="//jquery-translate.googlecode.com/files/jquery.translate-1.3.7.min.js"></script>
3)<script type="text/javascript" src="/scripts/jQuery/jquery.cookie.js"></script>
4)<script type="text/javascript" src="/scripts/jquery.bt.js"></script>
5)<script type="text/javascript" src="/fancybox/jquery.fancybox.pack.js"></script>
6)<script type="text/javascript" src="/scripts/common.js"></script>
7)<script src="/scripts/jQuery/insert_active_flash.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
8)<script type="text/javascript" src="/SliderBox/js/jquery.galleriffic.js"></script>
9)<script type="text/javascript" src="/SliderBox/js/jquery.opacityrollover.js"></script>
10)<script type="text/javascript" src="/SliderBox/shadowbox/shadowbox.js"></script>
11)<script type="text/javascript" src="/scripts/jquery.als-1.1.min.js"></script>
12)<script type="text/javascript" src="/scripts/settingsEN.js"></script>
```

The minified version javascript where having conflict with prototype.js. I just removed the prototype.js file and arranged all reference file in sequence [**Sequence matters a lot**]

*Now the error is removed I was still wondering what was the actual issue with prototype.js ???*

Answer (score 3):

I read your question and search on site of every plugins that you use.

- [Any List Scroller](http://als.musings.it/)
- [Shadowbox.js](http://www.shadowbox-js.com/usage.html)
- [Prototype](http://prototypejs.org/download/)
- [Galleriffic](http://www.twospy.com/galleriffic/)

If something is missing plugin, publish it please.

I had the similar problem and I not used the `$.noConflict(true);`

If you project is the server that when this is open for take the file html.

I suggest for you that you insert the calling for external div in one file html.

And in every file html you can write the script with

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
   .............
    });
```

You can't calling the file external in  every file html because this create a normal conflict.

**AND..**

I suggest this site for look the last libraries... [Google-libraries-last](https://developers.google.com/speed/libraries/devguide)

**AND..**

```
I have optimized all these and have included only one jquery file of jquery-1.9.1.min.js but still not able to clear the conflict Here is the sequence used by me
```

This is better.

**AND:::**

For the error `TypeError: $ is not a function` depends how this function is implemented or write.
Possible error is `;` or `{`, `}` ,  `(` , `)`
This happens because another javascript library has been loaded and has overwritten the object `$()` shortcut for jQuery.
So when we include other javascript libraries besides jquery, we are exposing the jquery library to conflicts.
Many JavaScript libraries use  `$` as a function or variable name, just as jQuery does. In jQuery's case,  $ is just an alias for jQuery, so all functionality is available without using  `$`.
One solution if we need to use another JavaScript library alongside jQuery, we can return control of  `$` back to the other library with a call to `$.noConflict()` like:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="mootools.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
  $.noConflict();
  jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    // Code that uses jQuery's $ follow here.
  });
  // Code that uses other library's $ follow here.
</script>
```

Another solution is to reassign jquery object `$()` back to jquery library, wrapping up our call inside a function that reassigns $() object. Thus we make sure our code isn’t messed with Prototype, Scriptaculous, etc.

```
( function($) {
 // Your jquery code
} ) ( jQuery );
```

Suppose:

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.1/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/prototype/1.6.1.0/prototype.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/scriptaculous/1.8.3/scriptaculous.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
( function($) {
    // Assigning $ again to jquery
    $(document).ready( function() { alert("Now you can use to use '$' in your jquery code");  } );
} ) ( jQuery );

//this will fail
$(document).ready( function() { alert('This fails because $ has been modified outside jquery'); } );
</script>
```

This approach is a self-calling anonymous function style to avoid conflicts with jQuery. If you don't use it then you would have to type jQuery() instead of its object `$()`.
Example:

```
$(document) //won't work
jquery(document) //will work
```

Example on [JSFIDDLE.NET](http://jsfiddle.net/vcbYJ/)

**Finally**

```
Typeerror for null
```

Look on [jquery-documentready-controlid-is-null](http://czetsuya-tech.blogspot.it/2011/02/jquery-documentready-controlid-is-null.html)

Comment: novelty or maybe I can get more details on the errors @Swapneel Kondgule

Answer (score 2):

try to use [`.noConflict()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.noConflict/) in jQuery

```
<script  src="....../jquery-1.8.3.min.js"></script> 
<script type="text/javascript">
var jQuery_1_8_3 = $.noConflict(true);
</script>

<script type="text/javascript" src="...../jquery-1.4.2.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
var jQuery_1_4_2= $.noConflict(true);
</script>
```